# Duvida na integração de aplicação web com mobile

Tags: aplicação-web, mobile, framework, integração

Olá, estou com uma dúvida sobre como fazer a integração do meu sistema web já existente com uma aplicação mobile.

Já desenvolvemos uma aplicação web cuja arquitetura é basicamente a seguinte: REST (através da API do Jersey) como web service, Maven como gerenciador de dependências, hibernate e jetty como servidor de aplicação. Para autenticação utilizamos o Spring Security.

Agora, precisamos criar um app mobile utilizando Phonegap que possua forma de login no próprio app e também através do Facebook, porém pretendemos utilizar os mesmos serviços do portal web para acessar e gravar as informações. Isso é possível? Qual a melhor forma de integração? E sobre o login com o Facebook, qual o melhor framework utilizar?

Obrigada! Aguardo.

Answer (score 2):

Particularmente eu gosto e utilizo [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/), [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/) e [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/), juntos permitem fazer o que vc está precisando.
Como vc pode ver [neste link](http://ngcordova.com/) o ngCordova tem plugin para login através de redes sociais, e com AngularJs pode fazer a comunicação com a API.
Além de permitir desenvolver para multi plataformas.